# wait() for thread made via clone?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, clone

I plan on rewriting this to assembly so I can't use c or c++ standard library. The code below runs perfectly. However I want a thread instead of a second process. If you uncomment `/*CLONE_THREAD|*/` on line 25 `waitpid` will return -1. I would like to have a blocking function that will resume when my thread is complete. I couldn't figure out by looking at the man pages what it expects me to do

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int globalValue=0;

static int childFunc(void*arg)
{
    printf("Global value is %d\n", globalValue);
    globalValue += *(int*)&arg;
    return 31;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto stack_size = 1024 * 1024;
    auto stack = (char*)mmap(NULL, stack_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_STACK, -1, 0);
    if (stack == MAP_FAILED) { perror("mmap"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    globalValue = 5;

    auto pid = clone(childFunc, stack + stack_size, /*CLONE_THREAD|*/CLONE_VM|CLONE_SIGHAND|SIGCHLD, (void*)7);
    sleep(1); //So main and child printf don't collide
    if (pid == -1) { perror("clone"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    printf("clone() returned %d\n", pid);

    int status;
    int waitVal = waitpid(-1, &status, __WALL);

    printf("Expecting 12 got %d. Expecting 31 got %d. ID=%d\n", globalValue, WEXITSTATUS(status), waitVal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you see https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid under "Linux notes"?  I think `__WCLONE` may be what you want.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can use `wait` with threads according to the `clone` man page, is there a reason you aren't just using `std::thread`?

Comment: @NateEldredge yep, that was the first thing I tried :(

Comment: You might strace a program that does `pthread_join()` and see what system call it uses.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Why do you say that? The clone page is where I got the example and it uses wait. Also there's a _WCLONE flag so obviously it expects it in certain cases. Also yes there's a reason I don't use threads but its only specific to me

Comment: `When a CLONE_THREAD thread terminates, the thread that created it is not sent a SIGCHLD (or other termination) signal; nor can the status of such a thread be obtained using wait(2).  (The thread is said to be detached.)`

Comment: @AlanBirtles ugh. I must have misread that. I double checked and it really does say that in my copy of the man pages too. HOWEVER it also says "After  all of the threads in a thread group terminate the parent process of the thread group is sent a SIGCHLD (or other termination) signal.". So... it's hard to understand what it actually does. I only start one thread so according to the next paragraph it should have received a signal

Comment: @NateEldredge Great idea! I just tried it and there appears to be a futex. I'm not sure of the performance implications. I'm thinking maybe I could raise a signal as a workaround. If you look at alan and my comments it appears the man page for clone says both wait will not work on clone and it will work the paragraph below. It makes 0 sense to me but I'll tackle it in the morning. I'm sure a signal will be a fair solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call functions asynchronously with threads I recommend using std::async. Example here :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

int globalValue = 0;    // could also have been std::atomic<int> but I choose a mutex (to also serialize output to std::cout)
std::mutex mtx;         // to protect access to data in multithreaded applications you can use mutexes 

int childFunc(const int value)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    globalValue = value;
    std::cout << "Global value set to " << globalValue << "\n";
    return 31;
}

int getValue()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    return globalValue;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // shared memory stuff is not needed for threads

    // launch childFunc asynchronously
    // using a lambda function : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
    // to call a function asynchronously : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async
    // note I didn't ues the C++ thread class, it can launch things asynchronously
    // however async is both a better abstraction and you can return values (and exceptions)
    // to the calling thread if you need to (which you do in this case)
    std::future<int> future = std::async(std::launch::async, [] 
    {
        return childFunc(12); 
    });

    // wait until asynchronous function call is complete
    // and get its return value;
    int value_from_async = future.get();

    std::cout << "Expected global value 12, value = " << getValue() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Expected return value from asynchronous process is 31, value = " << value_from_async << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's correct however in my specific case I'm actually writing assembly and my example is in C++ because it's easier to compile

Comment: Ok you did not specify "assembly" anywhere so I missed that :)

Comment: I 100% did not. I really should have. I edited it in now